# get url from web browser

Tags: c#

how can i retrieve URL for list box from web browser which is currently running on machine. using c#

Answer (score 1, accepted):

see this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/352236/reading-from-a-text-field-in-another-applications-window/365159), its for c++ but it may help

Answer (score 0):

```
    [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    static extern IntPtr FindWindowEx(IntPtr parentHandle,
    IntPtr childAfter, string className, IntPtr windowTitle);

    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    public static extern int SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd,
        int msg, int wParam, StringBuilder ClassName);

    private static string GetURL(IntPtr intPtr, string programName, out string url)
    {
        string temp=null;
        if (programName.Equals("chrome"))
        {
            var hAddressBox = FindWindowEx(intPtr, IntPtr.Zero, "Chrome_OmniboxView", IntPtr.Zero);
            var sb = new StringBuilder(256);
            SendMessage(hAddressBox, 0x000D, (IntPtr)256, sb);
            temp = sb.ToString();
        } 
        if (programName.Equals("iexplore"))
        {
            foreach (InternetExplorer ie in new ShellWindows())
            {
                var fileNameWithoutExtension = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(ie.FullName);
                if (fileNameWithoutExtension != null)
                {
                    var filename = fileNameWithoutExtension.ToLower();
                    if (filename.Equals("iexplore"))
                    {
                        temp+=ie.LocationURL + " ";
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        if (programName.Equals("firefox"))
       {
            DdeClient dde = new DdeClient("Firefox", "WWW_GetWindowInfo");
            dde.Connect();
            string url1 = dde.Request("URL", int.MaxValue);
            dde.Disconnect();
            temp = url1.Replace("\"","").Replace("\0","");
        }
        url = temp;
        return temp;
    }
```

Please do following to run this code
Add Reference > Com > Microsoft.Internet.Controls from VS.NET in your project

Download the bin from http://ndde.codeplex.com/ for DdeClient class and add it to your project