# How to get calculator amount on text box

Tags: c#, calculator

I have a application in which i want to open a calculator on a button click and once the operation are performed on calculator and calculator is closed, I want that value back to my text box.
How can I achieve this functionality.

```
  private void btnDollarTransferHelp_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Process myProcess = System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("calc.exe");
    }
```

I am using C# 4.0 and its a window based application.

Regards and Thanks

Comment: I'm not aware of any API which exposes the values/functionality from `calc.exe`.  Did you find one somewhere and you're trying to use it?  Or are you just assuming there must be one?  (If the latter, there probably isn't.)

Comment: @David:-  http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/csharpgeneral/thread/7065af59-00a0-4899-98c6-495bc704c41e

Comment: Might be quicker to write a calculator ... how much work could it be?

Comment: @Shashank: Nice to see the Microsoft MVPs are still as vague and unhelpful as always :)  That does seem to indicate that there might be a way, but given the lack of information I'm just not seeing it.  Perhaps something within the depths of COM, which I've spent a career successfully avoiding.  Sorry :(

Comment: Start your research with SPY++ which is already installed with your Visual Studio.

Answer (score 0):

You may use the Microsoft Script Control to implement the calculator functionality in your C# app. The control has a simple Eval() method to evaluate expressions that may range from simple "2+2" to VBScript commands. More information here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa227637(v=vs.60).aspx

Answer (score 0):

It is indeed simpler to implement a calculator in your app: reading the content of another's process window is not trivial! And being notified when the calculator is "about to close" is  even harder.

It involves, for sure, widows API (FindMessage/SendMessage) (see for example https://stackoverflow.com/a/360247/863564), probably [P/Invoke](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288468%28v=vs.71%29.aspx), probably even [hooking calc.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632589%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) (the technique used by Spy++ -- you need it to capture the WM_CLOSE message - see here what happens when you are [closing a window](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff381396%28v=vs.85%29.aspx))

(You need to capture WM_CLOSE, because it is the latest sensible moment to grab the result from the control on the window)

So, the alternative: a great one is [scriptcs](http://scriptcs.net/), but it may be well too much! A quick search revealed
[some](http://flee.codeplex.com/)
[great](http://ncalc.codeplex.com/)
[projects](http://csharpeval.codeplex.com/)

Either way, have fun!

Answer (score 0):

you could use an existing library e.g. http://nclac.codeplex.com to provide calculation within your application.